# Problems in implementing different colors in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement different color for every item of a list view but for the already asked questions I am unable to do so. I just have a listview in XML. How can I do do?

Comment: what you have tried ? post your code

Comment: As said in previous comment, you have to give more details if you really want good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change items from `XML`.
You should create `Adapter` for your `ListView`. In `getView` method of `Adapter` you can set color or what ever you want for each item at `position`. You can create `ArrayList<Integer> colors;` and set it for different items.